# Sample vs. Population

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to analyse the performance of my server by collecting performance data using standard tools such as Windows Performance Monitor, and then putting this data on Excel for analysis.

When I set up the data collector (as it's called), I can chose different intervals for collection, such as every 1 second, every 10 seconds and so on.

My first thought was that data collected every 1 second was going to be a "population", and greater intervals turned this data into "sample", but I soon realized that I could break it further into milliseconds and whatnot.

Is the data I collect at any given interval going to be considered "population" or "sample"?

Comment: In this situation, I think anything you get will be a sample and the population is something like the lifetime of the server or something.

Comment: @PeterFlom ha! That would make sense...

Comment: It depends on what you want to generalize to. Other servers? Your server? A given timeframe?

Comment: Recall that in Statistics, it's random samples that matter for inference. So if you sample at equal intervals (but with larger intervals), that does not give you a random sample. You have a time series with interval ... 1 second ... or whatever it is. Perhaps successive observations are independent in your case, but you would have to test for that.

Comment: @Placidia makes sense. So would the correct would be to collect various time series during different times of the day? I mean, one time series some time during the morning, one after lunch and another one at night?

Comment: @Ivan, that would be a stratified sample, that's about as far as you have taken it thus far. The biggest question is, what is it that you want to figure out, and how do you want to use this information for your decision making, which is what you need to add to your question.